# Criar parâmetro customizável para o Application Insights

Tags: c#, webforms, application-insights

Em um projeto WebForms (C# - .NET 4.6.2) estou utilizando a telemetria ***Application Insights*** do Azure, gostaria de enviar um parâmetro personalizado para a estatística.

Basicamente, quero enviar o ClientId para a telemetria, assim saberia identificar alguns gargalos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hoje ela apresenta esses dados acima, gostaria de enviar um personalizado, caso não exista como, terei que enviar via *Querystring* o `ClientId` mas não quero optar por esse caminho pois dará um trabalho enorme, além de considerar meio gambiarra.

Estou utilizando via JavaScript na MasterPage o código de rastreio, algo como:

```
var appInsights=window.appInsights||function(config){
    function i(config){t[config]=function(){var i=arguments;t.queue.push(function(){t[config].apply(t,i)})}}var t={config:config},u=document,e=window,o="script",s="AuthenticatedUserContext",h="start",c="stop",l="Track",a=l+"Event",v=l+"Page",y=u.createElement(o),r,f;y.src=config.url||"https://az416426.vo.msecnd.net/scripts/a/ai.0.js";u.getElementsByTagName(o)[0].parentNode.appendChild(y);try{t.cookie=u.cookie}catch(p){}for(t.queue=[],t.version="1.0",r=["Event","Exception","Metric","PageView","Trace","Dependency"];r.length;)i("track"+r.pop());return i("set"+s),i("clear"+s),i(h+a),i(c+a),i(h+v),i(c+v),i("flush"),config.disableExceptionTracking||(r="onerror",i("_"+r),f=e[r],e[r]=function(config,i,u,e,o){var s=f&&f(config,i,u,e,o);return s!==!0&&t["_"+r](config,i,u,e,o),s}),t
    }({
        instrumentationKey:"minha key"
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Além da `instrumentationKey` você pode passar algumas outras informações, dentre elas:

```
appUserId: string
accountId: string
```

Se você jogar o valor do ClientId em `appUserId` conseguirá ver essa informação no **Application Insights**

Maiores informações em: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/application-insights/app-insights-javascript

Comment: ótimo, uma luz no fim do túnel, parece q tem também user.id em users, vou testar... valeu! dando certo já marco como resposta.

Comment: Show! Espero que resolva :)